# Avoid using raw SQL for PgPromise inline query formatting using columnset

Tags: javascript, pg-promise

```
 const userPhoneNumber = await transaction.one(pgp.as.format(`${pgp.helpers.update({
      modifiedById: login.objectId,
      modifiedTimestamp: now,
      phoneNumber
    }, columnSets.userPhoneNumbers.forUpdateById)} WHERE object_id = $/objectId/ AND removed = $/removed/ AND userId = $/userId/ RETURNING *`, { objectId, removed: false, userId }));
```

Right now I am doing this in my code. I want to be able to

1. Utilize column set
2. Use pgp.update method along with column set to generate SQL

However, I am not sure how to utilize query file here as well. How can I use query file so I can avoid using RAW SQL string in my javascript code?

Right now I can only think of doing query file like so

`{statement:raw} WHERE object_id = $/objectId/ AND removed = $/removed/ AND userId = $/userId/ RETURNING *`

But this feels abit hackish to inject partial raw statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you declare statically your [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html), object according to the columns and the table that you use. For example:

```
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['col1, col2', 'col3'], {table: 'my-table'});
```

When it is time to execute the query, you prepare your `WHERE` condition like this:

```
const where = pgp.as.format(' WHERE object_id = ${objectId} AND removed = ${removed} AND
  userId = ${userId} RETURNING *', {objectId, removed, userId});
```

Then you can generate a complete `UPDATE` sql like this:

```
const updateSql = pgp.helpers.update(data, cs) + where;
```

Now you can execute that sql.

> I am not sure how to utilize query file here

In your example there isn't much point in using an external query file, though you can, if you want, as explained further.

You can create the following file:

```
${update:raw} WHERE object_id = ${objectId} AND removed = ${removed} AND 
userId = ${userId} RETURNING *
```

Then you load it like you would any other `QueryFile`:

```
const qf = new pgp.QueryFile(path, options);
```

And then you can generate a complete SQL query like this:

```
const updateSql = pgp.as.format(qf, {
    update: pgp.helpers.update(data, cs),
    objectId,
    removed,
    userId
});
```

Comment: Looks like I have to either redundantly use queryfilr or write some raw sql string in the code. Idk why I feel constructing raw sql as not a neat solution haha

Comment: @Zanko Library `pg-promise` is for executing raw SQL. So what is your issue with preparing a raw SQL then? Those who do not like writing SQL or do not understand it well usually go for an ORM. Library `pg-promise` is all about best performance + ultimate flexibility.

Comment: @Zanko If my answers satisfies your question, then please accept it. b.t.w. I am the author of `pg-promise`, so you won't find a better answer anyhow :)

Comment: yes I will. I have no issue preparing a raw SQL. I was just not sure if my approach is correct and normal. I thought I would have to utilize query file in order to put SQL into its own ".sql" extension to benefit from external formatting. I am not used to writing raw SQL amongst javascript code. It's unfortunate that if we want to utilize `pgp.helpers.update` for multiupdate with condition we would have to append with some raw sql string :(

Comment: @Zanko Raw-Text SQL is safe, as long as it comes pre-formatted, which is exactly your case. I believe you will find use of external SQL files indispensable as you move along, as you start writing complex SQL queries, and getting them updated automatically after a change in a DEV environment - saves tons of time ;) See the list of benefits here: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#query-files

Comment: Yea I am currenly using query file mostly for `SELECT` query. Haven't found much use for INSERT/UPDATE since most of them can be conveniently prepare by pgp.helpers.